# Generating user specified amount of random vowels/consonsants java

Tags: java, random, append, stringbuffer

I am trying to make a program that will choose a random assortment of 9 letters where the user specifies how many each of consonants and vowels to select.

So far I have:

```
char consonants [] = {'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'};
char vowels [] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
String word = "";
int howManyVowels, howManyConsonants;

public void generateLetters(){
    for(int i = 0; i < howManyVowels; i++){
        word.append(vowels[Math.random(howManyVowels)*5]+1);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < howManyConsonants; j++){
        word.append(consonants[Math.random(howManyConconants)*21]+1);
    }
}
```

The first error I get is: "error: method random in class Math cannot be applied to given types".

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: "error: method random in class Math cannot be applied to given types" start with fixing that and then fix all your other compilation errors.

Comment: do you know how I can fix that error?

Comment: Why do you think `Math.random(howManyVowels)` is going to compile?

Comment: I thought Math.random would randomize the vowels and howManyVowels would then get the number of vowels.

Comment: And what made you think that? When you program thinking things for no reason is not going to get you far instead you should read the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--